# What is the difference between various Facebook API Page "instagram" fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

If one queries the Facebook Graph API for a page, there are (at least) four fields one can request relating to Instagram:

1. **connected_instagram_account** - Instagram account connected to page via page settings
2. **instagram_business_account** - Instagram account linked to page during Instagram business conversion flow
3. **instagram_accounts** - Linked Instagram accounts for this Page
4. **page_backed_instagram_accounts** - Linked Page Backed Instagram accounts for this Page

The values can vary quite a bit and I can decipher a few of these but the Facebook Graph API documentation is not that clear on these items. So, I was wondering if anyone has or can clearly define each and differentiate one from the other.

Here is an example of one page that has 3 different values across the four fields (connected_instagram_account and instagram_business_account are the same):

```
-- instagram_accounts: #<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Array [#<Hashie::Mash id="...995">]>>
-- connected_instagram_account: #<Hashie::Mash id="...004">
-- instagram_business_account: #<Hashie::Mash id="...004">
-- page_backed_instagram_accounts: #<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Array [#<Hashie::Mash id="...234">]>
```

I am assuming this is the definition of a [connected_instagram_account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/#via_page) and this is the definition of [page_backed_instagram_accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/#pbia). Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

So, what about instagram_accounts?

If anyone can add some clarity or better yet, point to good definitions, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have answers to most of this question...

If I query a certain Facebook Page, it returns values for all four Instagram fields: **page_backed_instagram_accounts**, **instagram_business_account**, **instagram_accounts**, **connected_instagram_account**. The section below shows an edited version of what is returned and what happens when I try to access each using the [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user):

```
page_backed_instagram_accounts=#<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Array [#<Hashie::Mash id="964...289">]>
ERROR: "OAuthException: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (biography) on node type (InstagramUser)"

instagram_business_account=#<Hashie::Mash id="178...143">
#<Hashie::Mash followers_count=X follows_count=Y ... username="<public handle>" website="https://www.../"> 

instagram_accounts=#<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Array [#<Hashie::Mash id="423...525">]>>
ERROR: "OAuthException: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (biography) on node type (InstagramUser)"

connected_instagram_account=#<Hashie::Mash id="178...143">
#<Hashie::Mash followers_count=X follows_count=Y ... username="<public handle>" website="https://www.../">
```

As you can see, the Instagram API can access **instagram_business_account** and **connected_instagram_account** (which are the same account in this case) but not **page_backed_instagram_accounts** and **instagram_accounts**.

However, if I try to access the same account IDs based on the [Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-user/) definition, I get complementary results:

```
page_backed_instagram_accounts=#<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Array [#<Hashie::Mash id="964...289">]>
#<Hashie::Mash follow_count=0 followed_by_count=0 has_profile_picture=true id="964...289" is_private=false is_published=false media_count=0 profile_pic="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/..._a.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com" username="...758"> 

instagram_business_account=#<Hashie::Mash id="178...143">
ERROR: "OAuthException: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (follow_count) on node type (ShadowIGUser)"

instagram_accounts=#<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Array [#<Hashie::Mash id="423...525">]>>
#<Hashie::Mash follow_count=J followed_by_count=K has_profile_picture=true id="423...525" is_private=false is_published=true media_count=1 profile_pic="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/...a.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=d7ef...2dc&oe=5D0006BC" username="<public handle>"> 

connected_instagram_account=#<Hashie::Mash id="178...143">
ERROR: "OAuthException: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (follow_count) on node type (ShadowIGUser)"
```

As you can see in the second example, the Marketing API can access **page_backed_instagram_accounts** and **instagram_accounts** but not **instagram_business_account** and **connected_instagram_account**.

So, from what I can tell, **page_backed_instagram_accounts** and **instagram_accounts** are (Marketing API) Ad accounts, which would need to be accessed via the [Marketing API][3].

A couple of other things to note:

1. The account in **page_backed_instagram_accounts** appears to have an automatically generated username, is not published (`is_published=false`).
2. While account in **instagram_accounts** has the same username as the account in **instagram_business_account** and **connected_instagram_account**, it actually has a slightly different `followers_count`, `follows_count`, and a different ID.
3. The Instagram API reports against node type `InstagramUser` while the Marketing API reports against node type `ShadowIGUser`.

I believe that **page_backed_instagram_accounts** contains an automatically generated Ad Account for all accounts just in case there is no other Ad Account associated with an Instagram account. Still, it would be good to see a more definitive set of definitions for these fields returned for a Facebook page via the Graph API.

Comment: tx, this really helps